# Entity framework 7 batch insert as one transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

In Entity Framework 7 what would be the best way to do batchInsert to a table which is mapped using entity framework but I want to make sure that this is one transaction so either all objects are inserted or none?

THanks for hints!

Comment: The question is unclear because `SaveChanges` already does what you want. It persists all pending changes to all tracked objects in a single transaction. What are you actually trying to do and what does your code look like? I suspect you're not using EF as an ORM but as a database connection or driver. It's not

Comment: In any case, what you ask is explained in the docs, at [Efficient Updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7). Batching is enabled by default but can be configured. Batching isn't the same as BULK INSERT though which uses minimal logging. EF isn't a database driver so it doesn't deal with bulk inserts. Different databases have *very* different ways of implementing client-side bulk imports.

Answer (score 2):

Little bit changes on @Zohair post.
You can replace foreach loop by following statement.
**dbContext.YourEntities.AddRangeAsync(entities); //Entities will be your List or Collection.**

```
using (var dbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
    using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // Perform your batch insert operations here
            dbContext.YourEntities.AddRangeAsync(entities);

            // Save changes to the database within the transaction
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Commit the transaction if everything is successful
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions and roll back the transaction if an error occurs
            transaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entities should be an array if you go with this approach.
Also you must have corresponding DbSet<type of your entity> in your context.

Comment: There should be no need to specify a transaction, because you don't have a foreach loop anymore, and SaveChanges() implements its own transaction. It is only needed when you have multiple SaveChanges() that you want to bundle into one transaction

Comment: @GeorgesMafkas Ideally IEnumerable should be passed, so we can also use List<T>.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need having a transaction.

```
using (var dbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
   // Perform your batch insert operations here
   dbContext.YourEntities.AddRangeAsync(entities);

   // Save changes to the database within the transaction
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

1. entities should be array

This way if something fail with any of your objects during save, everything rollsback.

Comment: There is no need for entities to be an array. AddRangeAsync has 2 overloads, one that takes params object[] and one that takes an IEnumerable. So entities should just implement IEnumerable. For example a List https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrangeasync?view=efcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of Transactions & SaveChanges() method, I can share a sample code with you:

```
using (var dbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
    using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // Perform your batch insert operations here
            foreach (var entity in entitiesToInsert)
            {
                dbContext.YourEntities.Add(entity);
            }

            // Save changes to the database within the transaction
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Commit the transaction if everything is successful
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions and roll back the transaction if an error occurs
            transaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```